# Can't pass selenium driver as an argument to a function using `pool.starmap`

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I can't pass selenium driver as an argument to a function using `pool.starmap`.

Here is a minimal reproducible verifiable example:

**Main code:**

```py
from wait import sleep
import multiprocessing
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

secs = [1,2,3,4,5]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(sleep,[(driver,x) for x in secs])
    print(results)
```

**Wait.py:**

```py
import time

def sleep(driver,t):
    time.sleep(t)
    return f'slept for {t}'
```

I get this error `TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object`. How can I get around this? I looked around online but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `driver.set_page_load_timeout("time in seconds")` for the sleep of the driver ?

Comment: No this is just a mre. My actual code is different. The problem I am facing is that I can't pass driver to the function ....